# Pine script tradingview Value of highest volume with percentage on column

Tags: pine-script, volume, indicator

I am trying to put value of each volume on column of bar.But still havent got solution to how to do it.i am learning pinescript.Please guide me on how to put lable or value directly on column.I am attaching photo of another indicator that showing values on top of column.But this incator overlay is false and mine is true.If i can get same or nearby result then is also ok for me.I know it's tricky to plot values on column but i am sure there is also way to do it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Hlh.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your volume values in the format that you want, you will have to manually convert them to a string like so :

```
f_get_volume_string(_volume) =>
    string _volume_string = na
    if _volume >= 1000000000
        _volume_digits = round((_volume / 1000000000) * 100) / 100
        _volume_string := tostring(_volume_digits) + "B"
    else if _volume >= 1000000
        _volume_digits = round((_volume / 1000000) * 100) / 100
        _volume_string := tostring(_volume_digits) + "M"
    else if _volume >= 1000
        _volume_digits = round((_volume / 1000) * 100) / 100
        _volume_string := tostring(_volume_digits) + "K"
    else
        _volume_string := tostring(round(_volume * 100) / 100)
    _volume_string
    

vol_lab = label.new(x = bar_index, y = close, style = label.style_label_left, text = f_get_volume_string(volume))
label.delete(vol_lab[1])
```

This function will return the volume value as a string you can use in the label. If you want it to 3 decimal places, use `* 1000` and `/ 1000`

Comment: Once again Thanks @rumpypumpydumpy. You are so helpful.your code almost solve my problem.as usual i changed to my preference.i finally used following code = if volume > volume[1] * 5 vol_lab = label.new(x = bar_index, y = volume, style = label.style_label_down, color = #00000000, textcolor = col, size = size.tiny, text = f_get_volume_string(volume)). Thanks once again if you allow me then i can click on accept answer. Also i am new on stackoverflow so i dont know that is there any way that gives likes to answer or any users .

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest way I know of to achieve what you want with overlay = true. You will also need to make sure that under Chart Settings you set the bottom margin to zero.

```
//@version=4
study("Volume Values", overlay = true, scale = scale.none, max_labels_count = 500)
hh = highest(volume, 500)
plot(hh * 5, color = #00000000)

col = close < close[1]? color.lime : color.red

plot(volume, color = col, style = plot.style_columns)

if volume > sma(volume, 20)
    vol_lab = label.new(x = bar_index, y = volume, style = label.style_label_down, color = #00000000, textcolor = col, size = size.tiny, text = tostring(volume))
```

By having that invisible plot for `hh * 5` (it doesn't need to be 5, adjust to your needs) you can "flatten" the volume columns to the bottom of the chart window

Comment: thanks for your support. I managed to get what i want from your code.Almost result are good but i have one query .i managed to get value of volume on top of column but the value not comes in k or million its coming in as whole three to more digit.i am getting following result.https://ibb.co/BtPb3kh . what is solution for that to get value in K or M.Thanks